# SQLite how to declare as Byte Array?

Tags: sqlite

I've got a SQLite database. I'd like to create a field and declare it as type Byte array but I don't know what SQLite calls something that would be of type Byte Array. How would I do this?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You're looking for [BLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

From the webpage:

> **BLOB -** The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

Here's an example of making a table with two columns - an id and some data, which is a BLOB:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, data BLOB);
```

Answer (score 5):

To add an info - official is BLOB, but when building SQLite DB is Visual studio, use type "image" which is the alias for BLOB