# Can I Store Byte[] values into SQlite Database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need to Store Byte[] values into SQlite DataBase and Need to fetch the values in the form of Byte[]?

Comment: read about the BLOBs in sqlite

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280105/sqlite-how-to-declare-as-byte-array) might help you

Comment: yes @Sudhakar you can do it using blob in sqlite

Comment: **Q:** `Can I... ?` **A:** **`YES.`**

Answer (score 0):

Make column datatype as BLOB(Binary Large Objects).and it accepts any byte data.